# Generating Pseudorandom numbers: Middle-Square Approach

Tags: random

I was reading about middle-square method to generate pseudo-random numbers. But one thing that bothered me is that with the same initial seed isn't my pseudo-random number series going to be the same every time. Whereas, it should not be reproducible again no matter what.

For example, if I choose my initial seed to be 1234, my series would be 2343, 4896, 9706, and so on.....

 And I'll get the same sequence if I use 1234 as my seed again.

OR 

Have I misunderstood the concept in some way? Please clarify this for me.

Comment: Maybe read the wikipedia article on the algorithm first: *Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin. (cont: For [...] there is no such thing as a random number - there are only methods to produce random numbers, and a strict arithmetic procedure of course is not such a method.)* - Von Neumann.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I know it doesn't produce a truly random number. That's why I have used the word pseudo-random. But even then pseudo-random should also be non-reproducible using same seed (even if for a short sequence)

Comment: That's exactly what the seed is providing you: a reproducible way to get the same string of random numbers.

Comment: Alright. Thank you :-)